# Contacts view iphone SDK

Tags: iphone, uitableview, contacts

When we click on a specific contact in the contacts app in the iphone SDk, we see the image of the person, the name and the tableview with details of the person. I would like to know how to generate that view exactly ? . I tried having a table view slightly below and tried to add a view with the image and the name above the table view. But i was not able to get the gray stripe background image.

Is there a better way to do what i want ?

Comment: Do you know of the AddressBookUI.framework?

Comment: yes. But i want to implement something custom.

Comment: did you figure out how to build a custom solution that's just like the Contacts view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume this is what you're trying to do:

[alt text http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/9929/screenshot20100402at828.png](http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/9929/screenshot20100402at828.png)

That top Cell is a custom UITableViewCell, with a clear background.  There are a lot of ways to [subclass a UITableViewCell](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=subclass+UITableViewCell&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8).  You would just position the UIImageView so that it's on the left side of the cell and then create UILabels for the Name and Company.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AddressBookUI framework. You get this view for free in there, it will add the contact to the users main contacts but there is also a delegate method that returns the person just added back into your application I believe.